# XML dialogue tree in Unity not parsing information correctly

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have tried to setup a Dialogue tree within unity using XML (I have not used XML much before so am unsure if the way i am going is correct at all)

So I am trying to get the first text element from this dialogue tree but when i call the XML file and say where it is i am getting the everything stored in that branch.

Am i using the correct .XML to be able to do this also as i seen people say use .XML.LINQ or .XML.Serialization not just .XML is this correct for my case ??

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DialogTree
{
    public string text;
    public List<string> dialogText;
    public List<DialogTree> nodes;
    public void parseXML(string xmlData)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlData));
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("dialoguetree/dialoguebranch");
        text = node.InnerXml;
        XmlNodeList myNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("dialoguebranch/dialoguebranch");
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in myNodeList)
        {
            if (node1.InnerXml.Length > 0)
            {
                DialogTree dialogtreenode = new DialogTree();
                dialogtreenode.parseXML(node1.InnerXml);
                nodes.Add(dialogtreenode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a picture of the XML.
So i am trying to grab the first element of text then late on there response it will go to branch 1 or 2

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<dialoguetree>
<dialoguebranch>
<text>Testing if the test prints</text>
    <dialoguebranch>
        <text>Branch 1</text>
        <dialoguebranch>
            <text>Branch 1a</text>
        </dialoguebranch>
        <dialoguebranch>
            <text>Branch 1b</text>
        </dialoguebranch>
    </dialoguebranch>
    <dialoguebranch>
        <text>Branch 2</text>
    </dialoguebranch>
</dialoguebranch>
</dialoguetree>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting everything in that branch because `XmlNode.InnerXML` returns everything in that node. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml?view=netframework-4.8) for more information on that.

You should use the `branch` as the base for only looking at its children, instead of starting at `xmlDoc` every time. Also, you need an entry point to get inside of the first `dialoguetree` element and then ignore that. Finally, I would only create one `XmlDocument` and just pass around nodes in your recursion.

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
public class DialogTree
{
    public string text;
    public List<DialogTree> nodes = new List<DialogTree>();

    public static DialogTree ParseXMLStart(string xmlData)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(new Stringreader(xmlData));

        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("dialoguetree/dialoguebranch");

        DialogTree dialogTree = new DialogTree();

        dialogTree.ParseXML(rootNode);

        return dialogTree;
    }

    public void ParseXML(XmlNode parentNode)
    {
        XmlNode textNode = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("text");
        text = textNode.InnerText;

        XmlNodeList myNodeList = parentNode.SelectNodes("dialoguebranch");
        foreach (XmlNode curNode in myNodeList)
        {
            if (curNode.InnerXml.Length > 0)
            {
                DialogTree dialogTree = new DialogTree();
                dialogTree.ParseXML(curNode);

                nodes.Add(dialogTree);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
string xmlStringFromFile;
DialogTree dialogue = DialogTree.ParseXMLStart(xmlStringFromFile);
```

All of this code is untested but I hope the general idea is clear. Let me know if you find any errors in the comments below and I will try to fix them.